# XML Document straight to Stored Proc Mapping in NHibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I'm building a mechanism to take XML data from a queue and call stored procs to save the data from the XML document directly to the database.  This seems like something that NHibernate could address, but of course most of the information I find discusses going from objects to database instead of another data format (XML, in this case).  Is there a way to use NHibernate in this fashion or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Thanks.

Comment: NHibernate is an ORM, so its purpose is to map classes to a relational database. Why do you think that NHibernate could be of any help here?

Comment: You're right--it's not specifically for this task, but what I need is  similar to one of the things that NHibernate does--maps object relationships to stored procedures in the database. In this case the object relationships live in XML document not in classes.  

I'm frustrated because this task seems so simple and I'd prefer not to have to rebuild this from the ground up (for the Nth time in my career).  There's gotta be a tool that does this, right?

Thanks,
Zeke

Answer (score 2):

I think NH is not the right tool for this. Its purpose is to map classes to a relational database. Unless you deserialize the XML to an object model and let NH do the mapping to the database, you can't benefit much from it.